# Not sure why the visible=FALSE, does not drop the variables in the report

Tags: r

Here is the code i used

```r
library(Tplyr)
library(reporter)
library(tidyCDISC)

data(list=c('adsl','adae'), package='tidyCDISC')

adsl <- adsl %>% filter(SAFFL=='Y') %>% select(USUBJID, TRTA=TRT01A, TRTAN=TRT01AN) #%>% 
  # group_by(TRTA, TRTAN) %>% summarise(n=n())

adae <- adae %>% select(-c(TRTA, TRTAN)) %>% inner_join(adsl, by='USUBJID')

adae <- adae %>% select(USUBJID, TRTA, TRTAN, AEBODSYS, AEDECOD) %>% distinct() %>% 
  mutate(all='Subjects with any Adverse Events',
         across(c(AEBODSYS, AEDECOD), ~ str_to_title(.)))

t <- Tplyr::tplyr_table(adae, TRTA) %>% 
  set_pop_data(adsl) %>% 
  set_pop_treat_var(TRTA) %>% 
  set_pop_where(TRUE) %>% 
  Tplyr::add_layer(group_count(all, by='Subjects with any Adverse Events')) %>% 
  set_distinct_by(USUBJID) %>% 
  Tplyr::add_layer(group_count(vars(AEBODSYS,AEDECOD))) %>% 
  set_distinct_by(USUBJID)

dt <- t %>% Tplyr::build() #%>% View() 
dt <- dt %>% mutate(ord_layer_1=ifelse(row_number()!=1,ord_layer_1+1,ord_layer_1))

names(dt) <- str_replace_all(names(dt),'\\s','_')

tbl <- create_table(dt, show_cols = 1:8) %>% 
  # define(ord_layer_index, label = "Variable", label_row = TRUE,
         # format = c("1" = "Cylinders",
                    # "2" = "Miles Per Gallon"), 
         # dedupe = TRUE, blank_after = TRUE) %>% 
  define(row_label1,  visible = FALSE) %>% 
  define(row_label2, label = "", indent = .25) %>% 
  define(var1_Placebo, label = "Placebo", align = "center", n = 86) %>% 
  define(var1_Xanomeline_High_Dose, label = "Xanomeline High Dose", align = "center", n = 84) %>% 
  define(var1_Xanomeline_Low_Dose, label = "Xanomeline Low Dose", align = "center", n = 84) %>% 
  define(ord_layer_index, visible = FALSE) %>% 
  define(ord_layer_1, visible = FALSE) %>% 
  define(ord_layer_2, visible = FALSE) 

pth <- file.path(tempdir(), "test1.rtf")


rpt <- create_report(pth, 
                     output_type = "RTF",
                     orientation = "landscape") %>% 
  titles("Table 1.0", 
         "Adverse Events",
         "Population: Safety") %>% 
  set_margins(top = 1, bottom = 1) %>% 
  add_content(tbl)

write_report(rpt)
```

within the define if we use visible=FALSE then that variable should drop but it does not

[image]

i dont want to display the highlighted column

Comment: You need to show the output of this code (and if possible desired output)and for the sake of courtesy and simplicity, remove the commented lines that do not explain anything needed to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the issue is spelling/grammar. I cannot use into your original data t test my theory, but in the creation of `tbl` a define statement (`define(row_label1,  visible = FALSE)`) uses `row_label1` but in the table itself the name is `row label1`. I think you need to use some kind of identifier: ` `or ' ' to name the column within the table creation to apply the`visible=FALSE` to it.

Comment: The data is coming from the package `tidyCDISC`, if you install this package , you can access the data. Also, in my code i have `names(dt) <- str_replace_all(names(dt),'\\s','_')` which renames the variables to replace the space with `_`

Comment: That may be true, but the OUTPUT shows there is no _  and the assumption is that you used the incorrect output from the code you showed, meaning the report was generated after the table was created and the attempt to replace the space with _. That output table shows the name with the space. So, that means somehow the variable name coming into `tbl` creation did not have that underscore. I tried to run your code, but I get errors all over the place so I cannot reproduce it. The easy way to figure it out is look at tbl before you do anything else to it.